# двойной вызов функции

Tags: javascript, opencart

При добавлении товара в корзину скрипт срабатывает два раза, соответственно в корзину добавляется удвоенное количество товара, то же самое происходит при ручном изменении количества товара (дважды вызывается UpdatePx())
Пример http://missbloom.ru/cveti/anemone/anemon-sinij

Comment: если не нашли причину, то в коде UpdatePx() можно поставить счетчик вызовов. если счетчик > 1, то не выполнять код.

Comment: @Stack - нет задачи, которую нельзя было бы решить добавлением некоторого числа булевских флагов.

Comment: @Igor _"нет задачи, которую нельзя было бы решить добавлением некоторого числа булевских флагов."_ -- :) если много чужого кода, и дедлайн на носу, то это лучший способ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Значит вы либо повесили обработчик два раза, либо дело в том, что событие всплывает и обработчик срабатывает один раз на дочернем элементе, а потом на родительском.
Добавьте в UpdatePx() первой строкой `console.log(this);`, и если увидите там два разных элемента - значит вам надо добавить `event.stopPropagination()` или `return false`. А если один и тот же - то ищите, почему (и где) обработчик два раза вешается.